# How can we cache inline SVG in Browsers?

Tags: javascript, css, html, svg

SVGs have been around for years due to its scalability and it is long-familiar that the benefit of inline SVG is one can manipulate it with CSS and JS, and when we want to repeat the same SVG over a html document, then we can use the `<use>` tag to reference the original element. Furthermore, inline SVGs could also reduce the number of HTTP requests.

However, many articles suggest (without explaining the details) that while we use inline SVG to save HTTP request, it is no longer cacheable by a browser as a separate subject, which means it is not reusable across the pages.

As I happen to use inline SVGs extensively for a project, I would like to know exactly how inline SVG (the renowned html5 element, which is a w3c recommendation) can be cached in browsers whilst using SVGs with `<img>` tag or `background-image` are cacheable.

If DOM is cacheable, then why can't the SVG DOM ? 
(which builds upon and is compatible with DOM Level 2. Ref: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/svgdom.html)

So far, the solution I came up with cachebility is to use [Data URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) 
(Also Ref: [Optimizing svgs in data uris](https://codepen.io/tigt/post/optimizing-svgs-in-data-uris) )
But by doing so, it loses the ability to deal with CSS and JS for styling and manipulation.

A few examples around the web suggest the use of JS to load cacheable resource or by replacing placeholder elements such as `<object>` tag, as well as using localStorage, [CacheStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CacheStorage) and [Service Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorker). But I still need some guide lines to get started to achieve an ideal solution.

Could someone shed me some light please?

-

-

-

Ref: [Caching SVG Sprite in localStorage](http://osvaldas.info/caching-svg-sprite-in-localstorage)

Ref: [Inline SVG and caching](http://blog.angryobject.com/inline-svg-and-caching/)

Ref: [SVG ON THE WEB](https://svgontheweb.com/)

Ref: [Do Inline SVGs Weigh Down Websites?](http://mmckinnon.com/blog/2015/do-inline-svgs-weigh-down-websites)

Comment: inline SVG is cached as part of the page. I don't really understand the question here.

Comment: @RobertLongson If it's cacheable, then could you elaborate any example please?

Comment: Note that if your svgs are from same domain, you could load them through XHR and include them thanks to a DOMParser, or load them in an `<object>` or `<iframe>` before extracting their content to your main document, keeping the *cacheability* and the CSS manipulations ability. http://plnkr.co/edit/7YJOjyzOVesY3pVAbAWa?p=preview

Comment: Maybe useful: https://css-tricks.com/inline-svg-cached/

Comment: @StephenR Awesome! that's exactly what I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Basic HTTP caching works based on URLs, and it is “all or nothing” - you can instruct the client to either take the whole resource from cache, or to reload it completely.

Now, by “inlining” your SVGs, you are making them part of the HTML document - they are not external resources any more, that could individually be checked for whether they can be taken from cache or need to be reloaded.

So, if you have three HTML documents that all have the same SVG image inlined, the code of the image will be loaded three times - *because* it is part of the three HTML documents.

Whereas, if the image was embedded as an external resource (as img, background-image, object, …), it would be loaded only once, on the first of those three HTML pages the browser loads. On the other pages, it will recognize, “hey, that external resource with this particular URL is in my cache already - no need to load it again.”

Comment: Could you explain how we can cache inline SVG in Browsers please?

Comment: Not directly - because of what I just explained. You can of course try and come up with other ways of loading the image - f.e., get the source code of the image via AJAX (that request can be cached individually), and then dynamically put it into the DOM as a new `svg` element … stuff like that would work. But if the SVG is part of an HTML document to begin with - then it will only be cached together with that HTML document, and can not be cached individually.

Comment: @kolunar check out the link I added under the OP question. CSS-Tricks appears to have figured something out