# Clone embed/object element with contentData

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to clone  tag with all of its contentData, to prevent second loading of a big svg. I've tried to cache it, but it seems that browser does not cache object data. Is there any way to clone loaded object or to cache its data?

Here is the example:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {

       var url = "image.svg";
       var obj = $('#o1');

       obj.on('load', function () {
           obj.clone().attr('id','o2').appendTo( "#f2" );
       });

       obj.attr('data', url);

   });
</script>

<div id = "f1">
    <object id = "o1"></object>
</div>

<div id = "f2"></div>
```

Comment: Did you check if this is helpful?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37832422/how-can-we-cache-inline-svg-in-browsers

Comment: "Whereas, if the image was embedded as an external resource (as object) it would be loaded only once" - This doesn't work. I can see that all object requests ignores caching. That's the problem.