# Caching svg files. Use an img tag or svg tag?

Tags: css, html, svg

I have many large SVG files (roughly 200kb after reducing the size with online tools). I really don't want the visitor to download all that text from my server each time they visit. I want to take advantage of CDN's and varnish caching.

If I use an SVG tag, the browser nor a CDN or Varnish will cache the svg code in the html doc. SVG has no src property.

If I use an image tag it will be cached but then I can not take advantage of the preserveAspectRatio and viewBox that the SVG tag has. I'd have to deal with div's and css for images to maintain aspect ratio when resizing the browser window. Something you'd think would be easier with SVG

My current resolution is this css on an img tag with an svg in the src attribute.

```
.myImage{ max-width: 100%; height: auto; max-height: 55vh;}
```

What I really want to do is this but obviously I can not:

```
 <svg data='images/mydoc.svg' viewBox="0 0 250 75" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
 </svg>
```

Im looking for ideas on how to handle SVGs. Do I really need to wrap all my img tag svg images in div tags with css to maintain aspect ratio on browser resizes? I just feel there is an easier way, something I am missing?

Comment: Load them with ajax and append them to the dom.

Comment: @Gabriel your comment has nothing to do with the question

Comment: Yes it does. He can load the svg code with ajax. An ajax request can be cached. And by inserting the code in the dom he can manipulate it and add styles and so on, while he's loading them async instead of having the code directly in the html. It's everything he's asking for. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @Gabriel Any request *can* be cached by the browser (in particular, I'm thinking of Service Workers) but the main question that OP has described is having the SVG's cached by a CDN and/or Varnish.

Comment: I'd recommend this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37832616/1851509

Comment: The point (as stated in the first paragraph) is to avoid sending the SVG code on each request, regardless of the whole page being cached or not. Therefore having them inline wouldn't be ideal. Using `img`s is not an option because, while they're cached, they are not accessible from js and css. I'm giving him a third option, which is not mentioned in the linked answer, to achieve both things at the same time. Which CDN he chooses is irrelevant. OP please clarify, sorry if I got you wrong.

Comment: I am using Varnish for file caching locally. I'm also using Cloudflare which is great for images. Cloudflare has some rules I could enable for documents I think but I have not dove into it too much. Are you saying create an ajax request with a flag on it thinking something like ?cacheMe=1 on the url so a CDN caching rule can pick up on it? It seems like we are getting into hack territory here but could be workable. Horrible to have to deal with that. SVG really needs an src attribute

Comment: General_Twyckenham the link you gave is not really an answer, but more or less strengthens my frustration for no native caching when using an svg tag. So I guess the answer is not natively but with some hacks you can.

Comment: My current resolution is this css on an img tag with an svg in the src attribute. .myImage{ max-width: 100%; height: auto; max-height: 55vh;} However, this does not allow it to grow in height if you wanted i to. Also it depends on how the browser renders the svg. I have read something about how the browser converts your svg to a png when loading it, so if you resize you are in effect resizing a rasterized image, not the svg (I can't back this up with a source however).

Comment: What you read is deffinitely wrong. Please edit your question to include the CSS sizing properties you want to use. Do you only use CSS for sizing, or do you want to apply styling to internal contents of the SVG?

Comment: Edited question a little. I do mention css and resizing. I do not want to apply styling to the internal contents of the svg files. I am treating the svg files as images, not as a document like they were intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sizing CSS is doing too much and not enough at the same time. You say you want to have a `max-width`, but you do not give a width. You only give a `auto` height in addition to a `max-height`. Any image with a size of 0px by 0px could fullfill these conditions.

What do you want to happen if the SVG is very wide but not very high? To me it seems you want it to have the full 100% width, but the height to shrink. What do you want to happen if the SVG is so high that it would surpass the `55vh` limitation if it stretched the full width? To me it seems you want it to stay smaller and move to the left.

For this, your `max-width` rule is superfluous, and a `width` rule is missing.

You can achieve that easily (with the [possible exeption of older IE versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30415980/svgs-not-scaling-properly-in-ie-has-extra-space)). - For this example, I am setting the SVG as a data uri for a HTML `<img>` source. This way it acts the same with regards to CSS and sizing as if it was an external file.

```css
.myImage{
    width: 100%; 
    max-height: 55vh;
}
```

```html
<img class="myImage" src="data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 250 75' preserveAspectRatio='xMinYMin meet'><rect width='250' height='75' fill='green'/></svg>">
```

The point here are the `viewBox` and `preserveAspectRatio`: they are applied, whether the SVG is inlined or included from an external file. You define an area for the `<img>` tag, and the *viewBox rectangle* is fitted inside, following the aspect ratio rules.

In short, if this sizing behavior fullfills your needs, go ahead and include external SVG files through `<img>` tags.

Comment: I think I really need to define exactly what I want it to do in the browser which I don't think I have done properly. If it can't be done with the img tag or if I don't like how it is being done with the img tag then I need to giveup caching or apply a hack like  Gabriel said in the comments of the question.